# Informixdb multiple connections

Tags: python, linux, informix

I'm trying to create multiple connections with Informix. The problem here is all my servers and my databases have the same name, so when I can't connect to them at the same time because I read this name should be unique!

Now I'm trying to use the command:

```
os.putenv('INFORMIXSQLHOSTS','/home/informix/etc/sqlhosts1')
```

So I can use multiple sqlhosts file, but this doesn't work. Also, I read it's a bad practice so I'm looking for the right way to do this.

I have 4 servers with the name:

```
cms_net
```

Also the database name is:

```
cms
```

all in different IP servers.

I hope someone can help me connect to these in the right way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try overwriting the host in the connection string.

I have a "irk1210" defined in the machine named "irk"

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ grep irk1210 $INFORMIXSQLHOSTS
irk1210shm onipcshm irk irk1210shm
irk1210 onsoctcp 9.20.143.225  3046   
dr_irk1210 drsoctcp irk 3047
```

From Python (I guessing that's what you are using) I can either connect using just "irk1210" as the server name (info will be picked from the sqlhosts file)

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2016, 21:04:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import informixdb
>>> conn = informixdb.connect('sysmaster@irk1210',user='informix',password='ximrofni')
>>> print conn
<_informixdb.Connection object at 0x9d287a0>
>>>
```

Or specify the whole information for the server (server/protocol/host/service)

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2016, 21:04:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import informixdb
>>> conn = informixdb.connect('sysmaster@irk1210|onsoctcp|9.20.143.225|3046',user='informix',password='ximrofni')
>>> print conn
<_informixdb.Connection object at 0x93c37a0>
>>>
```

Doing the later gives you the option to specify a different host (ip) for the server:

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 26 2016, 21:04:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import informixdb
>>> conn = informixdb.connect('sysmaster@irk1210|onsoctcp|10.1.1.10|3046',user='informix',password='ximrofni')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_informixdb.OperationalError: SQLCODE -908 in CONNECT: 
08004: Client unable to establish connection
IX000: ISAM error:  record is locked.

>>>
```

I got a -908 error because I have no server in 10.1.1.10 but it kind of prove that the driver is trying to connect to an ip different than the one specified in the SQLHOSTS for the irk1210 server

Comment: I think it's better than the sqlhosts env hack 8)